# removing subfigure captions without removing labels

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, labels, subcaption, back-referencing

I tried using subfigure along with a caption for these four images according to the code shown below.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
%\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g1_2}
    \caption{\SI{10}{\nano\meter}$\times$\SI{10}{\nano\meter} raw image of the surface of epitaxial graphene, $\left(U_T=+\SI{100}{\milli\volt}, I_T=\SI{500}{\pico\ampere}\right)$, $z=0\to\SI{34.768}{\pico\meter}$}
    \label{figp1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g2_2}
    \caption{\SI{10}{\nano\meter}$\times$\SI{10}{\nano\meter} raw image of the surface of epitaxial graphene, $\left(U_T=+\SI{100}{\milli\volt}, I_T=\SI{500}{\pico\ampere}\right)$, $z=0\to\SI{45.534}{\pico\meter}$}
    \label{figp1b}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g_bilayer_2}
    \caption{\SI{6.5}{\nano\meter}$\times$\SI{6.5}{\nano\meter} raw image of the surface of epitaxial graphene, $\left(U_T=+\SI{100}{\milli\volt}, I_T=\SI{500}{\pico\ampere}\right)$, $z=0\to\SI{47.548}{\pico\meter}$}
    \label{figp1c}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g_bilayer_zoom_2}
    \caption{\SI{2.3}{\nano\meter}$\times$\SI{2.3}{\nano\meter} zoomed in section from fig.\ref{figp1c}, $\left(U_T=+\SI{100}{\milli\volt}, I_T=\SI{500}{\pico\ampere}\right)$}
    \label{figp1d}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{STM imaging of different areas of the epitaxial graphene sample, prior to the deposition.}\label{figp1}
\end{figure}
```

The image result is as follows.
[image]

I would like to obtain the boundary of the resulting cross as a new path, which one can draw or fill.

So, I tried to remove the captions and try again with this code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
%\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g1_2}
    %\caption{\SI{10}{\nano\meter}$\times$\SI{10}{\nano\meter} raw image of the surface of epitaxial graphene, $\left(U_T=+\SI{100}{\milli\volt}, I_T=\SI{500}{\pico\ampere}\right)$, $z=0\to\SI{34.768}{\pico\meter}$}
    \label{figp1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g2_2}
    %\caption{\SI{10}{\nano\meter}$\times$\SI{10}{\nano\meter} raw image of the surface of epitaxial graphene, $\left(U_T=+\SI{100}{\milli\volt}, I_T=\SI{500}{\pico\ampere}\right)$, $z=0\to\SI{45.534}{\pico\meter}$}
    \label{figp1b}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g_bilayer_2}
    %\caption{\SI{6.5}{\nano\meter}$\times$\SI{6.5}{\nano\meter} raw image of the surface of epitaxial graphene, $\left(U_T=+\SI{100}{\milli\volt}, I_T=\SI{500}{\pico\ampere}\right)$, $z=0\to\SI{47.548}{\pico\meter}$}
    \label{figp1c}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g_bilayer_zoom_2}
    %\caption{\SI{2.3}{\nano\meter}$\times$\SI{2.3}{\nano\meter} zoomed in section from fig.\ref{figp1c}, $\left(U_T=+\SI{100}{\milli\volt}, I_T=\SI{500}{\pico\ampere}\right)$}
    \label{figp1d}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{STM imaging of different areas of the epitaxial graphene sample, prior to the deposition.}\label{figp1}
\end{figure}
```

Now the image result is as follows

[image]

This image concept is Ok with me, but unfortunately, the labels for the four images namely `\label{figp1a}`, `\label{figp1b}`, `\label{figp1c}` and `\label{figp1d}` do not seem to work any more, because I commented the captions within the subfigures. I need the second image with the labels working.

Comment: Do you want to print only `(a)` but not the text? If you remove everything, how to refer to `3.1(a)` if it does not exist?

Comment: Please do not post fragments only

Comment: No, but I should be able to refer to the image itself as 3.1(a), but I will put (a), (b), (c), (d) on the image corners within the image area not separately.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: What do you mean?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob: You're posting non-compilable fragments of code. There's no `\documentclass` etc. here, no list of used packages, no `\begin{document}...\end{document}` and the images are unavailable to us as well

Comment: but how do you want me to post?....for example, this is just one page from the entire thesis of mine. I'm sorry for sounding boorish, it's just that I'm not so used to the posting culture here so I might be making some mistakes.

Comment: Just follow @marmot’s suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make @Mico happy. The subcaption package has a command for this, namely `\phantomsubcaption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \missingfigure[figwidth=\linewidth]{marmots are cute}
    \phantomsubcaption
    \label{figp1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \missingfigure[figwidth=\linewidth]{koala bears are also cute}
    \phantomsubcaption
    \label{figp1b}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \missingfigure[figwidth=\linewidth]{but in this forum, people love ducks}
    \phantomsubcaption
    \label{figp1c}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \missingfigure[figwidth=\linewidth]{I dunno why}
    \phantomsubcaption
    \label{figp1d}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Marmots, koala bears and ducks.}
\end{figure}
The most important message is the one of Figure~\ref{figp1a}. But you may also
like the one of Figure~\ref{figp1b}. Figure~\ref{figp1d} contains a question.
\end{document}
```

[image]